# Clearing an interval that was set before

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/x5MY8/2/

HTML

```
<div id="easy">easy</div>
<div id="hard">hard</div>
```

JS

```
function test(mode) {
    var asd = this;
    this.mode = mode;
    setInterval(function () {
        alert(asd.mode);
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#easy').on('click', function () {

        var stuff = new test('easy');


    });
    $('#hard').on('click', function () {

        var stuff = new test('hard');


    });

});
```

Upon pressing the `easy` button, an event launches that alerts easy every second. If I press `hard` afterwards, it will start another event, and it will alert `easy, hard, easy, hard..`, but I want it to alert only what was pressed at the moment, so I have to clear the previous interval somehow. How can I do that? Somehow, I need to call `clearInterval` when a button is pressed on the other object, but I don't really know how to.

Comment: how about an [invervalID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x5MY8/3/

You need to store and clear the interval like so

```
var interval;

function test(mode) {

    var asd = this;
    this.mode = mode;

    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        alert(asd.mode);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way than to use a global var? I wanted it to be fully OOP.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc you should have something static to control intervals between objects. So you are stuck with global var, or test class static field, or wrapping work with intervals into separate static (helper) class

Comment: It needs to be outside this function, after how your organize your code is up to you but it's generally recommended to wrap your code with IIFE (closure) so it would take the variable outside the global scope. But `window` is an object anyway so it's still technically OOP ;)

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc as static field of `test` class: http://jsfiddle.net/x5MY8/7/

Answer (score 2):

Store it in a variable:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
//your code
},1000);
```

Now, you can clear using clearInterval:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: And where in my code do I call clearInterval? If I put it in the other events, it will not have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

clear the value when every  clicked

```
 var clear=0;

    function test(mode) {
        var asd = this;
        this.mode = mode;
        clear=setInterval(function () {
            alert(asd.mode);
        }, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#easy').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(clear); 
            var stuff = new test('easy');


        });
        $('#hard').on('click', function () {
       clearInterval(clear); 
            var stuff = new test('hard');


        });

    });
```

Comment: gillesc's answer is better: you can get error trying to clear interval with ID 0 (before first `setInterval` is called). Also you will have to call `clearInterval` before every `new test`, which is not good.

Comment: @Regent  Did you check  that code .it is coming error ..could you tel me setInterval what will rerurn

Comment: @Regent see this url http://jsfiddle.net/x5MY8/6/

Comment: @Regent Do you know ? setInterval function return some numbers

Comment: Yes, `setInterval` return ID (which is number). Also it turns out, that `clearInterval` will not produce error when you pass incorrect ID to it (like 0 in your example at first click). So the only problem in your code is with necessity of calling `clearInterval` before creating new object

Comment: @Regent who told it will return **id** ?

Comment: w3c does: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp